# Protect from replay attacks when using request signatures in secure API communication?

Tags: php, security, api, signature, man-in-the-middle

I've been reading up on API communication securities and trying to figure out the best way to build a secure API. **I know that OAuth and such exist, but I'm also trying to educate myself in the process and not rely on libraries.**

Basically I have a Web Service and in that web service users can register for API. They will be provided a Profile ID and secret key which they have to use to build the API request from another web system.

API request is built similarly to the way banks do it, all input data sent to API has to be sorted, hash calculated and then the hash sent to the server, like this:

```
// Profile data
$apiProfile='api123';
$apiSecret='this-is-a-good-day-to-be-a-secret-key';

// Input
$input=array();
$input['name']='Thomas Moore';
$input['profession']='Baker';

// To ensure that the order of variables checked and received is the same on both ends:
ksort($input);

// Using serialize() for simplifying things
// http_build_query() is another option, or just placing values in order
$input['hash']=sha1(serialize($input).$apiSecret); 

// Making a request to URL:
// Using file_get_contents() as an example, would use cURL otherwise
$result=file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/api.php?'.http_build_query($input));

// SERVER CALCULATES COMPARISON HASH BASED ON KNOWN SECRET KEY AND INPUT DATA
```

**This is really good and works. But!** My problem is the potential replay attack. If someone snatches this request URL, they can send it to the server again, even though they cannot change the data itself.

Now I've read some things about it that you should also either check the time or add a one-time-use token to the request, but I am unsure how exactly should I do that? Is sending a timestamp with the request really secure enough? (Receiving server would make sure that the request has originated few seconds within the time the request was made, if the clocks are somewhat in sync).

I could also add IP validations to the mix, but these can change and can be spoofed somewhat and are more of a hassle for the user.

I would love this one-time-token type of system, but I am unsure how to do this without exposing token generation to the exact same replay attack problem? (Last thing I need is allowing to give out secure tokens for middle-men).

Opinions and articles would be really welcome, I've been unable to find material that answers my specific concerns. **I want to say that my API is secure**, without it being just marketing speak.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to only allow token exchange via a secure channel (https), and you should have a unique hash per message. Include things like a timestamp and the ip of the client. If you don't use https, you are vulnerable to a firesheep-style attack.

Other than that, you are doing the token generation and exchange correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the vote of confidence, I'm just a paranoid perfectionist I suppose.

Comment: I might use an actual HMAC to avoid length extension attacks, though it looks like you're not vulnerable since you place the secret last rather than first. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack

Answer (score 2):

Sending the time (and including it into the cache) is really an option.

The other option would be 2-phase algorithm when you first request for the session token or a session key, then use it for the session, and its TTL is stored on the server (which can be time or number of requests allowed)

As for the session keys idea look at schemes like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Example of 1-time token algorithm:

1) client composes a request for the 1-time token, signs this request with the secret key and sends it to the server.

2) server generates the key, signs it with the same key and sends it to the client (together with the signature)

3) client verifies the token using the secret key

4) client composes the request, including the token, and signs the whole request body with the secret key, then sends to the server

5) server checks whole body integrity and the token validity, then sends the response (again it can be signed with the secret key for integrity and authorship verification)

Comment: Timestamp solution seems really iffy. Since my API framework and library that communicates with it are both open source, man in the middle could build a listener that listens and sends the exact same request within the limited 'timestamp' period, getting auth token in return. I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: see an update for the 2-phase api using the 1-time token.
also you can completely encrypt the communication using Diffie-Hellman or similar session key approach

Comment: If you wrap the transaction in TLS, that accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: yes, this is a practical approach, but @kristovaher asked for some explanation, so I put expanded version. Also, though they can use TLS, many public APIs still use tokens or 2-phase auth

Comment: Alright, got some good ideas from here. So the 'weakest request' is really the initial token generation one? But what would stop replay attack from occurring if the sent request is stolen and 'sent again'? For example, if it returns sensitive information? Timestamp is the only option? (So I just have to accept the window of opportunity before timestamp retires?)

Comment: I can't really see the weak point here if the token is one-time and the secret key is really secret. the token and virtually every request and response are signed and thus cannot be faked, the attacker in the middle can repeat the token request and get the valid token (other from the original), but without knowing the secret key he cannot compose any valid request. The only (obviously nonsense) option is to catch your request from p.4 and repeat it